# Cannot update child pom,which also a parent

Tags: java, pom.xml, maven-release-plugin

I haven't put groupId or artifactId
I have a parent pom

```
<version>0.1-SNAPSHOT</VERSION>

<modules>
<module>ModuleA</module>
<module>ModuleB</module>
</modules>
```

ModuleA:

```
<parent>
   <version>0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>
```

ModuleB:

```
<parent>
<version>0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>

<modules>
<module>ModuleC</module>
<module>ModuleD</module>
</modules>

<properties>
<something>${project.version}<something>
<properties>

<dependencies>
<dependency>
<version>${something}</version>
</dependency>
</dependencies>
```

So the problem is, when i do "mvn clean release:prepare2, it updates the parent and ModuleA, but doesnt update ModuleB.In addition,i get an error saying that requires another version for the dependency while its finding (${project.version}) and not (0.1)

****PROBLEM SOLVED:****

I have a parent pom

```
<version>0.1-SNAPSHOT</VERSION>

<modules>
<module>ModuleA</module>
<module>ModuleB</module>
</modules>



<properties>
    <something>0.1-SNAPSHOT<something>
    <properties>



<dependencyManagement>
<dependencies>
<dependency>
(no  version)
</dependency>
</dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

ModuleA:

```
<parent>
   <version>0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>
```

ModuleB:

```
<parent>
<version>0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>

<modules>
<module>ModuleC</module>
<module>ModuleD</module>
</modules>

<dependencies>
<dependency>
 "no  version"
</dependency>
</dependencies>
```